# VBA code for inserting table with some drop down values in excel

Tags: excel, vba, insert, dropdown

I am trying to write a VBA code for inserting a table with some dropdown values for Heading and also for Inline elements. But I'm confused about the data validation part.
I want to insert a table on 'Insert module' button click. that table should have suggestions for the heading and each row as well. Heading suggestions are different from row suggestions.

Here is my code for inserting the table and its working fine.

```
Dim objTable As ListObject
Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)
```

Comment: After you inserted the table successfully, apply whatever captions you want to its header cells.

Comment: I want to insert a  table with suggestions for heading and elements on a single customized button click. so that a user can simply click the button and can have a table with all data suggestions.

Comment: Quite. You already have the code for inserting the table. Now add code to modify its column captions.

Comment: Where are the values to build the dropdown lists to come from. Are they on the sheet or to be hard coded into the macro ?

Comment: need to hard code it into the macro. I tried it. but the issue is we can't predict the cell address of each table's heading and elements as it is dynamically created by the user.